# Free fonts with U+0CA0 (ಠ) character?

Tags: debian, fonts, unicode

The glyph ಠ comes from the alphabet of Kannada, a language which I do not speak, and if it weren't for the Internet as it exists, I wouldn't care to have any of its glyphs.

I recently discovered that GNU unifont had this glyph, so now when someone might post the emoticon meme ಠ_ಠ, I can see it properly.

However, anyone who has dealt with unifont knows that it is a poor-quality font that really only serves to have some example glyphs for every character. What are some better-quality TrueType Fonts that I can get on Debian that would have this glyph?

Comment: The title comes out as "Free fonts with  character?", not very useful. Maybe try transcribe it

Comment: I suggest : Free fonts with unicode 'KANNADA LETTER TTHA' character

Comment: There are probably more with it than without it, maybe your problem is locale related?  It shows in my browser (`Sans`) and cut and pasted into apps using `Liberation Mono` and `Anonymous Pro` fine.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0ca0/fontsupport.htm the list of fonts that support Unicode Character 'KANNADA LETTER TTHA' (U+0CA0) is :

Arial Unicode MS
Code2000
GNU Unifont
LastResort
Unicode BMP Fallback SIL

[image]

check http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0ca0/index.htm too, there's a lot of info on unicode characters

Comment: LastResort and Unicode BMP Fallback SIL are not real fonts (they do not contain glyphs for this character) but generic fallback fonts intended to help in detecting *lack* of proper fonts.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GNU Unifont, the following fonts contain glyphs for U+0CA0:

- Arial Unicode MS, a proprietary font bundled with various Microsoft software. Also purchasable separately.
- Code 2000, a font with obscure status, once distributed as shareware, now perhaps best characterized as abandonware. No official distribution site exists.
- Nirmala UI. Microsoft proprietary.
- Sun Ext-A. Available via [Alan Wood’s download page](http://www.alanwood.net/downloads/index.html). Probably freeware, but documentation is in Chinese.
- Tunga. Microsoft proprietary.
- Universalia Plus. An obscure font, probably compiled by combining existing fonts together without authorization. Documentation in Russian.
- Akshar Unicode, JanaKannada, Kedage, Mallige, RaghuKannada, Sampige, and Saraswati5. Freely downloadable according to information on page [Unicode fonts for Kannada](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Kannada.html) at WAZU JAPAN's Gallery of Unicode Fonts. The page is last updated in 2009. I have not checked these fonts, but some of them might be available.

Comment: Universalia Plus probably comes from https://unicode-table.com which uses the font "universalia" that consists of